# problems with jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a certain div refreshed on the page every 3 seconds. This div contains other divs inside it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#gamewrapper2').load('find.php #gamewrapper2');
}, 3000);
;
```

This code works but only if the page visited is domain/find.php and it doesn't work for domain/find.php?id=1000001

Maybe i don't understand something but shouldn't this function load take the block #gamewrapper2 from find.php and paste it into the block #gamewrapper2 of the current page?

Comment: That code should work in both cases, unless your php is returning the page differently in such a way that results in `#gamewrapper2` not existing. I'd suggest against loading in an entire page every 3 seconds just to get a small subsection of it though, seems like a lot of extra network traffic.

Comment: when i open domain/find.php?id=1000001 it displays ok for 3 seconds and then the  #gamewrapper2 dissapears

Comment: Right, but with the information you have given us thus far, it shouldn't be doing that. Provide more information so that we can help you.

Comment: when you say 'loading an entire page' what do you mean by that? I need a certain div refreshed, not the entire page, i was under the impression that the load method achieves just that

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to specify `#gamewrapper2`, `.load('file.php')` should work just fine, it should automatically search for the id that you are loading it into, since they are both the same.

Comment: if the #gamewrapper2 is not specified in the load then the entire page is loaded into the div

Comment: #gamewrapper2 div is created by php does this make a difference?

Comment: @SolomonClosson That's totally incorrect.

Comment: @user2088846 The `.load()` method loads the entire page via AJAX, then searches that document for the element(s) matching the selector, before inserting them into the element the function is being called against. You may only be using a section of it, but you're still loading the entire page.

Comment: using .load loads the entire page, then if you specify a selector such as #gamewrapper2, it will look for an element that matches that selector within the entire page and move it's contents to the target element.

Comment: This says otherwise:  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This is the part of PHP that summons the div

<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
echo "<div id=\"gamewrapper1\">";
echo "<div id=\"gamewrapper2\">";

Comment: No it doesn't @SolomonClosson

Comment: @JayBlanchard - You're right, misread it.

Comment: When you only need gamewrapper2.. why dont you modify your php code like this: <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo // the content of gamewrapper2; ... if it is possible

Comment: isn't this exactly what i wrote above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need to keep the query string on find.php? Something like:

```
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#gamewrapper2').load(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + ' #gamewrapper2');
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to pass variables into the php document:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#gamewrapper2').load('find.php #gamewrapper2', {id: 1000001});
}, 3000);
}
```

Additionally, you can provide a function callback when it has completed loading to perform some task...

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#gamewrapper2').load('find.php #gamewrapper2', {id: 1000001}, function(){
        alert("find.php has been loaded.");
    });
}, 3000);
}
```

[.load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You should probably use `$_POST['id']` to get the value from find.php.

Comment: doesn't work but i'm pretty sure this is why it doesn't. div gamewrapper2 only exists if $_GET['id'] is set so i somehow need to retrieve the game id from the browser and send it to find.php

Comment: I think you'll need to search for `$_POST['id']` in order to get it that way.  Updated answer.